# How to select or add date from react-date-picker in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I am doing cypress automation. I want to automate selecting the date from the react-date picker calendar.
Currently, I won't able to automate selecting the date.
I need help.

```
cy.get('#dateField').type('12-02-2020')
```

it's not working.
it's input type is disabled
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to update selector and make more specific for 'input' field

```
cy.get('#dateField input').type('12-02-2020')
```

in your first attempt I think cypress can't find where to type this value, check it out